# How can I export my color settings from Visual Studio 2013 and import on Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

At home I use Visual Studio 2013, however at work sometimes I have to use Visual Studio 2010.

I would like to use the same colors on both environments. I want to export the default Dark Theme from Visual Studio 2013 and import on Visual Studio 2010.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to export your settings them import them.  Might be easier to setup 2010 and import the settings them into 2013

Comment: It shows an error saying the versions are not compatible. I was hoping for some way around...

Comment: Export the settings for both versions and compare them with like Beyond Compare see if that makes a different

Answer (score 1):

Use [VisualStudio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe) from Microsoft MSDN

Simple to use and allows export/import

Comment: Extension is not support by 2010 and only supports importing 2012 themes

Comment: Sorry I missed the 2010 requirement but you can definitely import 2013  items, not just 2012

Comment: Yes it says that but he wants to import 201" settings into 2013 which isn't possible with the extension ( for good reasons )